# Scaling tall graphic to fit in page

Tags: xslt, apache-fop, docbook, docbook-xsl

I have a Docbook 4 document with several very tall graphics (not all but some of them are much taller than their width). I want them to scale to fit on the page automatically.

Is there a way to define this in stylesheet? There are over a 1000 graphics and I don't want to check them all by myself.

At the moment it looks like this:

```
      <figure>
        <title>Some Title</title>
        <mediaobject>
          <imageobject>
            <imagedata fileref="graphic.svg" width="100%" scalefit="1" contentdepth="100%"/>
          </imageobject>
        </mediaobject>
      </figure>
```

but its only fits the width not the height. So the graphic overlaps with the elements before and after.

As fop i have to use apache-fop.

Answer (score 0):

In order to scale the graphics with an fo:external-graphic, you can use the attributes [content-height](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslfo20/#content-height) and/or [content-width](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslfo20/#content-width) with the value 'scale-down-to-fit'